# Interpretation of an ODE in the Sense of Classical Analysis or Distribution Theory

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, distribution-theory

This problem and the following questions are motivated by a simple problem in the theory of [visco-elasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscoelasticity).

Assume that $\sigma:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function defined as
\begin{align*}
\sigma(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t\lt0 \\
\sigma_0 & t\gt0
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $\sigma_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that we are looking for a function $\varepsilon$ such that
\begin{align*}
&q_1 \dot{\varepsilon}(t)=\sigma(t)+p_1\dot{\sigma}(t),\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}, \\
&\varepsilon(0^-):=\lim_{t\to0^-}\varepsilon(t)=0,
\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where the over dot denotes differentiation with respect to $t$ and $q_1\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\,p_1\in\mathbb{R}$.

> **Question 1.** Does Eq.$(2)$ uniquely determines $\varepsilon(t)$ over $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$?

I suppose that the answer to Question 1 is *yes*. I am not sure about this, please correct me if I am wrong. Bearing this in mind, let us find this function.

**Direct Method**

If $t<0$ then the ODE in $(2)$ implies that $\varepsilon(t)=A$. But the initial condition forces $A=0$ and we have
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon(t)=0,\quad t<0.
\tag{3}
\end{align*}
If $t>0$ then the ODE reduces to $q_1\dot{\varepsilon}(t)=\sigma_0$ which has the solution
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon(t)=\frac{\sigma_0}{q_1}t+B,\quad t>0
\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> **Question 2.** How can I find the constant $B$?

In my text, the final answer is given as
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t<0 \\
\frac{\sigma_0}{q_1}t+\frac{p_1\sigma_0}{q_1} & t>0
\end{cases}
\tag{5}
\end{align*}

**Laplace Transform Method**

I checked the answer in $(5)$ via the Laplace transform method. If we define our Laplace transform as 
$$\mathcal{L}(f)(s):=\int_{0^-}^{+\infty}f(t)\exp(-st)dt\tag{6}$$
(note $0^-$ in the lower limit). Then we can easily obtain the above answer. Denoting that $\bar f(s):=\mathcal{L}(f)(s)$, using $\bar{\dot{f}}(s)=-f(0^-)+s\bar f(s)$ and $\bar\sigma(s)=\frac{\sigma_0}{s}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
q_1\big(-\varepsilon(0^-)+s\bar\varepsilon(s)\big)&=\bar\sigma(s)+p_1\big(-\sigma(0^-)+s\bar\sigma(s)\big) \\
q_1s\bar\varepsilon(s)&=(1+p_1s)\bar\sigma(s)\\
\bar\varepsilon(s)&=\frac{(1+p_1s)}{q_1s^2}\sigma_0\\
\bar\varepsilon(s)&=\frac{1}{q_1}\Big(\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{p_1}{s}\Big)\sigma_0\\
\varepsilon(t)&=\frac{1}{q_1}\big(t+p_1\big)\sigma_0\\
\varepsilon(t)&=\frac{\sigma_0}{q_1}t+\frac{p_1\sigma_0}{q_1}
\tag{7}
\end{align*}

which is the desired answer. But, I think that some part of this calculation is not allowed as I am sure that the direct method is completely OK!

Read the comments below Dylan's answer for an answer to this discrepancy.

---

**Further Observations**

The answer to Question 1 is *no* in the sense of classical analysis and *yes* in the sense of distribution theory. In conclusion, by just using classical analysis we cannot get anything more than Eqs. $(3)$ and $(4)$. Then it is natural to ask

> **Question 3.** How can we obtain the solution $(5)$ by just using classical analysis?

Indeed, the main problem we are interested to solve is some other problem. The limit of the solution of this problem coincides with $(5)$. Suppose that
\begin{align*}
\sigma_\tau(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq-\frac{\tau}{2} \\
\frac{\sigma_0}{\tau}\big(t+\frac{\tau}{2}\big) & -\frac{\tau}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{\tau}{2} \\
\sigma_0 & t\ge\frac{\tau}{2}
\end{cases}
\tag{8}
\end{align*}
is given. We are looking for a **continuous** function $\varepsilon_\tau(t)$ such that
\begin{align*}
&q_1 \dot{\varepsilon}_\tau(t)=\sigma_\tau(t)+p_1\dot{\sigma}_\tau(t),\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \\
&\varepsilon_\tau(-\frac{\tau}{2})=0,
\tag{9}
\end{align*}
Then, by just using classical analysis, we can prove that
$$\lim_{\tau\to0^+}\varepsilon_\tau(t)=\varepsilon(t),\quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\},
\tag{10}$$
where $\varepsilon(t)$ is the function given by $(5)$. However, this method is painful and lengthy, specially for more complicated problems. Distribution theory is a nice tool which can give us $(5)$ much much faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the following arithmetic should be interpreted in the sense of distribution theory.

Bearing in mind that $\dot\sigma(t)=\sigma_0\delta(t)$ with $\delta(t)$ being the Dirac delta function (or more precisely Dirac delta distribution), integrate the entire equation like this

\begin{align*}
q_1\int_{-\tau}^\tau \dot\varepsilon(t)\ dt &= \int_{-\tau}^\tau\sigma(t)\ dt + p_1 \int_{-\tau}^\tau \dot\sigma(t)\ dt \\
q_1\big(\varepsilon(\tau)-\varepsilon(-\tau)\big)&=\int_{-\tau}^\tau\sigma(t)\ dt +p_1\sigma_0\int_{-\tau}^\tau\delta(t)dt
\end{align*}

Then take the limit as $\tau \to 0^+$. You'll get

$$ q_1\big[\varepsilon(0^+) - \varepsilon(0^-)\big] = p_1\sigma_0 $$

Since $\varepsilon(0^-) = 0$, we have $\varepsilon(0^+) = \frac{p_1\sigma_0}{q_1}$ which is also the value of $B$.

Comment: (+1). Thanks for the attention. :) At first, I also thought like you but in this case we **cannot** apply the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_{a}^{b}f^{'}(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$ since the function $f$, i.e. $\sigma$ or $\varepsilon$ in our problem, is **not** continuous over $[a,b]$. So, I think although your solution gives the right answer but it does not make sense.

Comment: Furthermore, according to Eqs. (1), (3) and (4) in the question, you can directly check out that your first equation is readily satisfied without any restrictions on $B$. To understand my first comment better, try to check out the fundamental theorem of calculus for $\sigma$ given in Eq. (1). You will discover that $0=\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\dot\sigma(t)dt\ne\sigma(\delta)-\sigma(-\delta)=\sigma_0$.

Comment: @H.R. One should understand these operations in the sense of distribution theory, with $\dot{\sigma}(t)=\sigma_0 \delta(t)$. Thus indeed $\int_{-\delta}^\delta \dot{\sigma}(t) dt = \sigma_0$ if $\delta>0$. An equivalent way to say this is that in your "direct method" your condition to compute $B$ is that the jump in $\varepsilon$ at $t=0$ is given by $p_1 \sigma_0$ (i.e. $p_1$ times the jump in $\sigma$).

Comment: @Ian: Is there anyway not to use the distribution theory! :) I mean how would you obtain this answer directly?

Comment: @H.R. Strictly speaking no (you're taking derivatives of nondifferentiable functions). But "matching" in the sense of my edited comment is one way, and the Laplace transform is another way, to take these things into account without needing all the theoretical machinery of distribution theory. In the end you're using it anyway, though, because it is built into the definition of $\dot{\sigma}$.

Comment: @Ian: In my formulation of the problem, there is no derivative at the points of discontinuity so the problem is clearly defined in sense of classical analysis. However, I noticed that in the Laplace transform method, I was not really allowed to use $\bar{\dot{f}}(s)=-f(0^-)+s\bar f(s)$ as it is not valid for functions like $\sigma$ or $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Ian: by the way, are you "Ian Murdoch"? :)

Comment: No. Also that doesn't really matter, without dealing with this $\dot{\sigma}$ is nowhere to be seen in the problem, and the problem on the positive axis has no initial condition.

Comment: @Ian: Is it wrong to say $\dot\sigma(t)=0$ for $t>0$ and $t<0$?

Comment: That's true. ${}$

Comment: @Ian: I think that I got my answer. I would appreciate that if you write 
an answer so that I can accept it. :) Many thanks.

Comment: @Ian: This question indeed is a simple problem in the theory of visco-elasticity.  What is surprising for me is that interpreting the ODE in the distribution sense gives us a unique answer but interpreting it in the classical analysis sense the answer is not unique! Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: In a "classical" sense, the equation has a singularity at $t=0$, so no solution exists in $\mathbb R^+$ with the I.C. given

Comment: @Dylan: I think there should be something implicit in the distribution interpretation that if expressed explicitly in the classical analysis sense then they both will give the same answer. A mathematical interpretation should not change the physics of the problem. As Ian mentioned, expressing the jump condition can lead to the same answer in the classical analysis sense. But I am thinking how to interpret the jump condition physically! The jump conditions are implicit in the distribution interpretation.

Comment: One interpretation comes from rrgularizing $\sigma$ so that it has no jump but merely a sharp transition.

Comment: @Ian: I tried to explain your last comment in the last part of the question. Thanks for your valuable comments and guides. :)